# Entity Framework Core generates two select queries for one-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm building an EF Core provider for the Google Spanner db. I've bumped with an issue when trying to select an entity with **one to many** relationship.

For example, lets say I have the following entities:

```
public class Player
{
    public string PlayerId { get; set;}

    public string Name { get; set;}

    public List<Game> Games { get; set;}

}

public class Game
{
    public string GameId { get; set; }

    public string PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Player Player { get; set;}
}
```

Each Game is related to one Player and each Player has many games...

When running the following query:

```
ctx.Players
.Include(p => p.Games)
.Where(p => p.PlayerId == "123")
.Select(p => new {
    PlayerId = p.PlayerId,
    Games = p.Games
});
```

Two select queries are constructed and executed separately against the DB:

```
SELECT "p"."PlayerId" FROM "Players" AS "p" WHERE "p"."PlayerId" = '123'
SELECT "p0"."GameId" FROM "Games" AS "p0" WHERE '123' = "p0"."PlayerId"
```

Is it a known issue? Can I control the **SelectExpression** to be created only as one select (using join...)?

Comment: This actually is considered an improvement over EF6 `Include` processing - instead of retrieving a result set with a lot of duplicate values, it simply does 2 queries. And no, you can't control it.

Comment: OK, thanks! I understand...